# Bad practice when I want to check like this if an int is this number?

Tags: java, if-statement, numbers, switch-statement

I have to check if my `int n` equals `1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6`
Is it bad practice to do it like this:

```
//n = randomnumber
private final List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6);
if(numbers.contains(n)){
return;
}
```

or should I do a switch?

```
switch(n){

case 1:
     return;
break;


case 2:
     return;
break;
//...
case 6:
     return;
break;
}
```

I could also do if statmements but I guess I dont have to

Comment: Why not just do `if(n>=1 && n<=6)`?

Comment: Jesus, you are right, but can I still do it when its a "large" set of numbers? Lets say 100?Also what to do when I want to use the 4 as example? @OHGODSPIDERS

Comment: That entirely depends on that "large set of numbers" and how they are related.

Comment: You only need two numbers, the ones that define the borders of the specific set of numbers. You can just do it like @OHGODSPIDERS did with the range 1..6, just take 1..100. Having a set of non-consecutive numbers will have to be tackled differently.

Comment: Lets say they are non-consecutive - what to use then? @deHaar

Comment: @Woody Just a check for each range individually should be enough then. So basically `if(n>=1 && n<=10 || n>=20 && n<=30)` and so on

Comment: Is this "smarter" or better than my attempts? @QBrute

Comment: if you have non-consecutive numbers, your approach is fine. There are several ways to achieve the goal, so you'd have to decide case by case which is most readable (and preferrably non-bloated). I'd for instance never use a switch expression/statement to achieve  this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you.

Comment: @Woody you need to be more specific. You are being so vague it makes answering almost impossible. In your example you gave a simple range that can be checked with a simple if. The same can be done for every other range. If you want to check if a number is a multiple of 2 that can also be easily checked or if you want to check if a number starts or ends with a specific digit. But if the 100 numbers you want to check have absolutely no logical relation to another and are completely random then we are dealing with a whole different problem. Ask about the specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you, my bad. Lets say they have absolutely no logical relation to another and are completely randomly. I question was already answared because I only have 1-6 but nowI want to know the next step when they are completely random  @OHGODSPIDERS

Comment: `Set.of(1,7,33,...,1029).contains(n)`